# Is it possible to trace insert/update/delete commands in EF 5 (DbContext)?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I would like to know, if it´s possible to trace `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements which get generated by the `SaveChanges` method of the `DbContext` class; and if yes, how can I get the command text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways that let you see generated SQL statements, just pick up the one that fits to your needs:

- SQL Profiler: Step by step procedure [here](http://www.paulkiddie.com/2013/03/tracing-all-sql-generated-by-entity-framework/)
- Intellitrace: [Here](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/vs2010-intellitrace-and-entity-framework-database-interaction/)
- EF Tracing provider: [Here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/03/31/using-tracing-and-caching-provider-wrappers-with-codefirst/)

And if you're working on a web app, consider to use one of those tools:

- Miniprofiler: [Here](http://miniprofiler.com/)
- Glimpse: [Here](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/03/27/glimpse-1-2-released-with-support-for-entity-framework-ado/)

Comment: Thanks alot. The problem is that most of the tools require SQL Server and/or Visual Studio Ultimate... but how can I trace commands when working with Oracle and Visual Studio Professional?

Comment: EF Tracing provider is not DB or VS version related. Anyway, you might want to give a try to external profiler tools like [EFProfiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf), there's a 30 days trial.

Comment: But isn´t the EF tracing provider related to the SqlClient?